# Binary byte mistaken with newline in Linux serial comunication

Tags: c, linux, binary, serial-port

I'm working with a Serial communication interface; a SBC (**TS-7200**) running Linux Kernel 2.6.36 sends data via RS232 to a PC (running Windows). The data is encapsulated in packets (byte per byte) and sent. The issue occurs when the TS tries to send an integer `(uint8_t)(10)`, which, notably, is the ASCII for `\n`, the termination char `(0xA)`; not random right?!

The strange things is that, if I use an **Arduino Uno** to do the same exact operations, an integer 10 will be sent and received without a problem! So my conclusion would be that Linux takes `0b00001010` like a `\n`, flushes the serial buffer and doesn't send `10` over, while Arduino doesn't. Searching online I found that a file can be opened in **binary mode** (O_BINARY) or **file mode** but apparently this ins't available in Linux; is that right? Is there a way to make Linux behave like Arduino?

Thank you,
Federico

PS: I forgot to mention I'm working with **C**

Comment: How do you send an integer with a value, say, `1000`?

Comment: You don't need `O_BINARY` on Linux because, like virtually every sane operating system, it doesn't do any conversion of line ending characters. It's only Windows with its bizarre CR+LF line endings where you need `O_BINARY`.

Comment: Please see [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266992/no-o-binary-and-o-text-flags-in-linux)

Comment: I open the serial communication with: `COM2 = open("/dev/ttyAM1", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);`
and to write I use `bytes_writed=write(COM2, number, 1);`

Comment: @WeatherVane I already saw that post, but I'd say the Windows counterpart works properly (LabVIEW does it by default, I guess(?)), otherwise how would you explain that it's working with Arduino and not with the TS?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the serial port in "raw" mode:

```
struct termios  tty;
unsigned int    sfd;

/* Open the serial port */
sfd = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

/* Get current port config. */
tcgetattr(sfd, &tty);

/* Set youd speed/parity, etc. */
/* ... */

/*
Set raw mode, equivalent to:
tty->c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP
            | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
tty->c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
tty->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
tty->c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
tty->c_cflag |= CS8;
*/
cfmakeraw(&tty);

tcsetattr(sfd, TCSANOW, &tty);

/* Do read/write */
```

Be careful to de-activate even software flow control (XON/XOFF) in order to send all the data in the packet.

Please check the article [How to read a binary data over serial terminal in C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12437593/6811918)

Comment: @PaulR You did realize the "link" is to an SO answer?